# Eigenfunction for $-\Delta u = \lambda u $ on $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u$ be the eigenfunction for the equation :

$$-\Delta u = \lambda u \text{ on }\Bbb{R}^n$$

with $\lambda>0 $ and $n = 3$, If we assume that $|u|\to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, and $\|u\|_{H^1(\Bbb{R}^n)}<\infty$ can we deduce that $u = 0$.

I have three standard idea to handle this problem, the first one is maximum principle, here we have the unbounded domain, it seems not applicable to this problem .

Another idea is we may use the energy method. to bounded $\int|u|^2$, I have no idea how to bound this term.

The third idea is if we have some gradient estimate $$\sup_{B_R} |u|\le \frac{C}{R}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Bbb{R}^3)}$$
or something like this, however I don't know how to build this type of estimate?

Comment: Try Fourier transform.

Comment: Hi @Feng , the reason that the equation above can have non zero solution of the type for example $e^{i\sqrt{\lambda} w\cdot x}$ is this type of function does not has well defined Fourier transformation correct?

Comment: But your example dose not belong to $H^1$. For all functions in $H^1$, we can perform Fourier transform.

Comment: @Feng  , I have another question , does the elliptic regularity hold for $\Bbb{R}^n$ if so, we only needs $L^2$ then?

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, if $u\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfies $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ for some $\lambda>0$ in the sense of distribution, then $u\in H^2(\mathbb R^n)$. You can prove this result by recalling the definition of $H^2$ through Fourier transform (not the defintion through the $L^2$ of weak derivatives).

Comment: thank you I got it.